# Fuzzy address lookup using Google

Tags: google-maps, fuzzy-logic

Has anyone ever tried to use google map api for fuzzy address matching?  My thinking is that if I make two calls to google to get a proper name and consistent address format, this would make the compare easier. Is there a better approach?